# Azure ML Decision Tree Visualization Download

Tags: pdf, download, visualization, decision-tree

When visualizing the decision tree outputs in the trained model, is it possible to download the visual into a .pdf format or any other format that is readable? Currently I am taking screenshots but the quality of the tree is terrible if there are many leaves and I need this for reporting purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can download the visualization directly as a PDF. However, you can download the output from the score model and then use that output to create the visualization.
Regards,
Jaya